# Using the localStorage in a multiuser

Tags: javascript

I use the localStorage to write and read values from/to controls of HTML forms. Is this object "multiuser proof" i.e. is one concurent user isolated from another user when concurently using the same form ? Since the localStorage is client-side, the answer should be "Yes", but I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Yes, The answer is __Yes__

Comment: Client-side. You self-answer your question

Comment: Yes localstorage depends on browser. So only one user uses one browser at a time so for different users it will be different and non accessible.

Comment: what if the user does multiple logins from the same browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thin since localStorage is client-side, so the answer is "Yes", but
>   I wanted to make sure.

Yes, localstorage is on the browser.

Browser is a **single-threaded** and **single-user** environment.

There is **no possibility of concurrency** or **race condition** on a browser.

Each user has its own browser session (by virtue of being in different machines, VM's etc), so nothing is shared on the client side. At a time only one user works on a system (even if the system is shared or has multiple profiles).

So, you can be totally sure that localstorage is totally thread-safe :).

> what if the user does multiple logins from the same browser?

In practice, a user will have only one active login session from one browsing session. Even if you have multiple google accounts, only one will be able to login at a time.

You can still prefix the user-id to the key names you use, for example

```
localStorage.setItem( user_id+"_preferedLocale" , "en");
```

and fetch for a specific logged in user as

```
var userLocale = localStorage.getItem( user_id+"_preferedLocale" );
```

Comment: so unless the user is using a new Browser window, there can only be one active session at any given point of time. if there are more windows, each storage is unique.